# Kill hive queries without exiting from hive shell

Tags: shell, hive, hiveql, hivecli

Is there any way we can kill hive query without exiting from hive shell ?. For Example, I wrongly ran the `select` statement from some table which has million rows of data, i just wanted to stop it, but not exiting from the shell. If I pressed `CTRL+Z`, its coming out of shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. press `Ctrl+C` and wait till command terminates, it will not exit from hive CLI, press `Ctrl+C` second time and the session will terminate immediately exiting to the shell
2. from another shell run

   `yarn application -kill <Application ID>` or
    `mapred job -kill <JOB_ID>`

Comment: `hadoop job -kill <JOB_ID>` is deprecated, use `mapred job -kill <JOB_ID>`

Answer (score 1):

First, look for Job ID by:

```
hadoop job -list
```

And then kill it by ID:

```
hadoop job -kill <JOB_ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with the second option

`yarn application -kill <Application ID>`. Get the application ID by getting onto another session. 
This is the only way I think you would be able to kill the current query. I do use via beeline on hortonwork framework.